# Как воспроизводить звук?

Tags: c#, uwp

Могу ли я воспроизводить звук напрямую через спикер, как в `DirectShow`? `DirectShow` к сожалению не доступен в UWP. Я конечно мог бы использовать `Media Foundation`, но, к сожалению, `AudioGraph` принимает фреймы только в следующем формате (32 bit; Stereo; 48 kHz; IEEE Float). При добавлении `AudioFrame` из другого `AudioGraph`, то все работает. Но вот создать новый `AudioFrame` из массива байтов я не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
MediaElement me = new MediaElement();
me.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
me.Play();
```